# how to specify flex item when they wrap in unknown width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a container with two child. i set flex-wrap property and value wrap. In Small device when they break in unknown width then how can i set margin/padding between two item?

https://jsfiddle.net/irojabkhan/w1x5phya/4/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  font-size: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hello World</div>
  <div class="item">Keep Learning</div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply add margin-bottom to the first element

Comment: Which margin/padding do you mean? Top, bottom, vertical, horizontal, ...?

Comment: It can be margin-top or margin-bottom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply added margin-bottom to parent-block;

```
`.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.child-1,.child-2{
    margin-top: 30px
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the margin-bottom to the amount of space you require:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Set this to whatever you want it to be*/
}
```

```html
.contai<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hello World</div>
  <div class="item">Keep Learning</div>
</div>
```